# Ember-data script problems

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to create my first app by following the instructions on the "Guides" page. Since "Ember-Data" wasn't included in the starter kit, I've looked at the following sites for the .js file:

- http://builds.emberjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/ember-data-0.13.js
- http://builds.emberjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/ember-data-0.13.min.js
- http://cloud.github.com/downloads/emberjs/data/ember-data-latest.js

I may not being doing this properly, but I save each by right clicking the page, hitting "Save As", and then saving in my scripts folder (this is an ASP MVC app).

My declarations then look like this:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ember-1.0.0-rc.6.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ember-data-latest.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> //have been putting the ember-data scripts here
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/App.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

However, I get this same error each and every time:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'extend' of undefined
```

This error references 'App.js: 3', which is the first line in this block of code:

```
App.store = DS.store.extend({
    revision: 12,
    adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
});
```

..so basically none of my ember-data scripts are working. Can someone point me to a download or let me know if they see something I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This are the resources that work well togheter.

- http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js
- http://builds.emberjs.com/handlebars-1.0.0.js
- http://builds.emberjs.com/ember-latest.js
- http://builds.emberjs.com/ember-data-latest.js

and then include them

The order is important here.

And if you are using the latest ember-data you should define your store like this:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
});
```

Note that since revision 13 of ember-data you don't need to define the revision in your store definition.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm guessing I'm not doing anything wrong in right-clicking the page w/the code and selecting "Save as" am I?

Comment: @NealR, basically not, but the store definition you have is slightly wrong, note the capitalized `DS.Store.extend` instead of `DS.store.extend`

Comment: @NealR you should anyway when possible get the latest builds from the builds.emberjs.com site

Comment: I added all three in this order: 1. handlebars, 2. ember-latest, 3. ember-data-latest and it still broke. On the `DS.Store.extend` line. Here is the message: `JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'extend' of undefined or null reference`

Comment: Ah, I didn't see your comment about the capital `S`. That fixed the problem... thank you very much!!!!